# Oracle: multiple joins onto one column

Tags: oracle

I'm joining a table onto another as per the normal method (attached to an ID column). This is working fine and returns a row when I run the query. However, if I try to join another table onto the same ID column, I get an empty result set. Is this legal in Oracle, or will I have to find another way around it?

Cheers.

**EDIT**: The code:

```
INNER JOIN    TABLE2
ON            TABLE1.ID = TABLE2.ID

INNER JOIN    TABLE3
ON            TABLE1.ID = TABLE3.ID
```

I've also tried joining table 3 onto table 2, but that had no effect, either

Comment: Also, can you confirm that any of your IDs in the first table _actually_ exist in the second.

Comment: Yes, they all exist. They've got identical names, too, just to be safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that my issue was not in the join statement, but in the *WHERE* clause underneath it. The join works fine.

To answer my question, therefore: **Yes, it's legal**.